# Silent printing of a PDF in Python

Tags: python, windows, pdf, printing, silent

I'm trying to print a PDF with Python, without opening the PDF viewer application (Adobe, Foxit etc.). I need also to know when printing has finished (to delete the file).

[Here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.windows/6558) I found this **implementation**:

```
import win32ui, dde, os.path, time
from win32api import FindExecutable
from os import spawnl, P_NOWAIT
...
pd = "C:\\temp\\test.pdf"
pdbits = os.path.split(pd)
readerexe = FindExecutable(pdbits[1],pdbits[0])

spawnl(P_NOWAIT,readerexe[1],"DUMMY") #I added "DUMMY" to avoid a weird error

time.sleep(2)

s = dde.CreateServer()
s.Create('')
c = dde.CreateConversation(s)
c.ConnectTo('acroview', 'control')

c.Exec('[FilePrintSilent("%s")]' % (pd,))

s.Destroy()
```

But it throws this exception at the `ConnectTo` line:

```
dde.error: ConnectTo failed
```

Someone knows how to solve it? Or has a **different solution** for silent printing? Or at list can give a link to a **reference for `ConnectTo`**? Could find nothing on the web about it.

Working with: Python 2.7, Windows 7, Acrobat Reader 10.0

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suggest you install [GSView](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/get49.htm) and [GSPrint](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/gsprint.htm) and shell out to `gsprint.exe` to print the pdf.

```
p = subprocess.Popen([r"p:\ath\to\gsprint.exe", "test.pdf"], 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print stdout
print stderr
```

I have used this in a industrial label printing solution, works great.

When the `gsprint.exe` program exits (i.e. after the call to `communicate`), you can delete the pdf file.

Comment: GREAT!! I solved this issue that tormented me during days. I add that it's required to install both GhostScript ("back-end", downloadable from http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) and GSView ("front-end", which includes GSView and GSPrint, downloadable from codeape's first link)

Comment: Yes - the Ghostscript toolchain is the way to go here. It is worth noting that almost all printing solutions for Linux and other Unixes nowadays use GS programas one way or another.

Comment: Thank for this. I printed my txt file with esc sequences into pcl made printer, converted it to pdf and printed silently with ghostscript to a non-PCL printer :)

Comment: Shall I use gsprint in a commerical software?

Comment: what is the solution to print microsoft's DOC/DOCX silently?

Comment: and how to set print on the both sides of paper without setting this as the default for printer

Comment: Options to gsprint.exe are documented in gsprint.html inside the installed files. The options for both side printing are `-duplex_vertical` and `-duplex_horizontal` I believe.

Comment: As for doc/docx I guess there is no simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method i use;

but you need to install two files and put them on the dir of the main app:

- GHOSTSCRIPT
- GSPRINT

the parameter is to augment the quality of printing so if you want you can change them

```py
    def print_pdf(self, word_path_org, printer_name):
        try:
            # Initialize COM
            pythoncom.CoInitialize()

            # Get the full path of the Word document
            word_path = os.path.abspath(word_path_org)

            # Get the base name without extension
            base_name, _ = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(word_path_org))

            # Construct the full path of the PDF file
            pdf_path = os.path.abspath(f"{base_name}.pdf")

            self.convert_to_pdf(word_path,pdf_path )

            try:
                GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH = "GHOSTSCRIPT\\bin\\gswin32.exe"
                GSPRINT_PATH = "GSPRINT\\gsprint.exe"
                # Check if the PDF file exists
                if not os.path.exists(pdf_path):
                    raise FileNotFoundError(f"PDF file not found: {pdf_path}")

                command = f'-ghostscript "{GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH}" -printer "{printer_name}" -color -r600 -dColorDepth=24 -dJPEGQ=95 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sOutputICCProfile=sRGB.icc "{pdf_path}"'
                win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'open', GSPRINT_PATH, command, '.', 0)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error  during printing: {e}")

            finally:
                # Uninitialize COM
                pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
                time.sleep(2)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
```