# Send to printer a text over an image in python

Tags: python, pywin32

Using python, wxpython and sqlite in a windows system. I'm trying to print some certificates/diplomas/cards with an image in the background and the name of person/text over it.

I know the basic steps to print the text using win32print from Pywin32 but:

1. I dont know how to add an image and set it to background.

   ```
   while .....

       .....

       # Query sqlite rows and collumn name and set the self.text for each certificate

       .....

       # Now send to printer

       DC = win32ui.CreateDC()
       DC.CreatePrinterDC(win32print.GetDefaultPrinter())

       DC.SetMapMode(win32con.MM_TWIPS)

       DC.StartDoc("Certificates Job")

       DC.StartPage()

       ux = 1000
       uy = -1000
       lx = 5500
       ly = -55000

       DC.DrawText(self.text, (ux, uy, lx, ly),win32con.DT_LEFT)

       DC.EndPage()
       DC.EndDoc()
   ```

   This printer-code is inside a while loop calling each people name from a sqlite database per check condition.
2. All the names of database was printed at same page. How do I command the printer to spit out 1 page per name from the database?
3. A simpler approach or module to deal with printers (paper and/or pdf) will be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be feasable with WxPython, but I do not know enough to help you.

However, you can try to take a look into [Python Image Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) :

Example code :

```
import sys
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw

txt = 'C\'est mon texte!'
txt2 = '??,??!'


im = Image.new("RGBA",(300,200),(100,155,100))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

draw.text( (0,50), txt )
draw.text( (0,100), txt2)
del draw

im.save('font.png', "PNG")
```

and the result :

[image]

Comment: Humm... i see now how to put a text over a image. But how to send it to the default printer? And how to improve the resolution/quality?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you instead use [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/) to create a PDF and then send that PDF to a printer using gsprint.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4498956/3571

Comment: Sorry. No... I dont want or think I need use any external EXE file for that. If was the case is simple just set as default printer a virtual pdfprinter like primopdf or any other.