# Automatically print downloaded files

Tags: python, web, printing, odoo

I have a small dillema; I'm developing a sort of web point of sale application using python as a controller. What I need is a way to automatically print a sequence of PDF files generated and downloaded by the browser to a default physical printer. I assume most of my POS terminals will work on windows yet my application server was designed on an Ubuntu Server plataform. Any Ideas?

PS: This is a module developed as an OPENERP application

Answer (score 1):

You can embed JavaScript into the PDF which can do the printing.
I am not sure if you can print the file after it is being downloaded or only if the PDF is opened in the browser.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074070/how-to-send-a-pdf-file-directly-to-the-printer-using-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074070/how-to-send-a-pdf-file-directly-to-the-printer-using-javascript) you can find more information.
It also depends which browser you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to configure the browser to download the files to a certain location. A python script could watch that directory and print the files when they appear.

See this question for printing PDFs from Windows with Python: [Silent printing of a PDF in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498099/silent-printing-of-a-pdf-in-python)