# how to call the printer within python with pycups

Tags: python, printing, printers, cups, network-printers

what I want to do is call the printer in the network to print a pdf file  in python. I have found the pycups lib. but the terrible doc make it really hard for me to get-started. And also the cups seems to be a big things to learn which make me really confuse now. 
so can anyone give me some pycups example or other things?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silent printing of a PDF in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498099/silent-printing-of-a-pdf-in-python)

Comment: It seems not. I would like to use cups to manager many local-network printer. and call anyone as needed. So I need a server to manager the printer and ready for requests to print file with correct printer.Run sever in windows seems not a good ideas.and cups seems can only be installed on mac or unix-like-system. so the windows is not a choice.