# Automate printing of a page from PDF

Tags: python, windows, selenium, automation

Let me walk you through the steps I need to automate:

1) Go to URL, fill out form, and click submit

2) This downloads a PDF

3) I want to only print second page of PDF

So far, I've been using python with selenium to automate step 1 and 2. Now I am stuck at printing the second page of downloaded PDF. I would love it to be OS universal (I know I would have to write different logic between Windows and Mac), but if that is not possible, Windows is fine.

So far I have looked at

[Silent printing of a PDF in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498099/silent-printing-of-a-pdf-in-python)

But I was wondering if there any other solutions. Thank you

Comment: This [SO Answert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51681595/7414759) shows how to print single pages.

Comment: Thanks @stovfl. That was perfect.